# How to retrieve individual lines of data from a .dat file using PHP?

Tags: php, html

I am failing to understand how to retrieve individual lines of data (For Eg. First name, age, birth year, sex) from a `.dat` file using PHP. I am confused by everything I have read online. I need to get each line out of text from the `.dat` file and assign each line its own `$variable` to be used later for print. What I have so far.

```
<?php
$personalinfo = fopen("personaldata.dat", "r");

$firstname = <!-- line one of .dat file -->;
$age = <!-- line two of .dat file -->;
$birthyear = <!-- line three of .dat file -->;
$sex = <!-- line four of .dat file -->;
$weight = <!-- line five of .dat file -->;

fclose($personalinfo);
print("<p> $firstname you are $age years old, born in $birthyear, you are $weight lbs. and $sex.</p>")
?>
```

Comment: Isn't using a DB not an option, if not a safer option? Not to mention being easier and more manageable than a text file.

Comment: `$lines = explode("\n", $personalinfo); $firstname = $lines[0];...etc` ? To be honest, I'm completely with @Fred-ii- on this one. Is a DB not an option?

Comment: @Fred-ii- I guess I understand, I just needed to know how to read individual lines from a .dat file. Safety isn't a issue.

Comment: Darren's way is the way to go then.

Comment: @Darren I am not sure I know what a DB is. Is there a simple way to retrieve what is on line 1 of a .dat file and assign that line of text to a $variable and then repeat that for the next 1-6 lines?

Comment: @NicholasFoxworthy A DB is a database.

Comment: @NicholasFoxworthy See my answer for grabbing the lines and corresponding values.

Comment: You may also have to give us a sample of your `.dat` file, with about 3 lines of it. You may need to do a big of extra PHP magic, depending on how you've got it setup if it's comma seperated, tab, or other, and how you want it displayed.

Comment: .dat file contains only this each space marks a new line of text:
    mark
    15
    5
    male
    1990

Comment: Will it contain more later? That could be an issue and with the answer given.

Comment: @Fred -ii- No it will not contain more data in the future.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Dat File Format**

There are a broad range of formats for .dat files. First, you have to determine how the data is formatted in your .dat file. It sounds like you're saying the file is line-delimited (every line represents a value.)

**Accessing File Lines (File Function)**

PHP makes it easy to grab one line of a file resource at a time, as the file function returns an array formed from the file lines:

```
<?php
$personalinfo = file("personaldata.dat");

$firstname = $personalinfo[0];
$age = $personalinfo[1];
$birthyear = $personalinfo[2];
$sex = $personalinfo[3];
$weight = $personalinfo[4];
print("<p> $firstname you are $age years old, born in $birthyear, you are $weight lbs. and $sex.</p>");
```

**Accessing File Lines (Old School)**

```
<?php
$personalinfo = fopen("personaldata.dat", "r");
$firstname = fgets($personalinfo);
$age = fgets($personalinfo);
$birthyear = fgets($personalinfo);
$sex = fgets($personalinfo);
$weight = fgets($personalinfo);
fclose($personalinfo);
print("<p> $firstname you are $age years old, born in $birthyear, you are $weight lbs. and $sex.</p>");
```

Comment: Can I close the file before the print or do I have to close the file after print? Also thank you very much for the answer!

Comment: @NicholasFoxworthy You don't have to close this call, as it's not returning a resource, it's returning an array :)

Comment: @NicholasFoxworthy And, sorry, I had left your fopen() call in there instead of file(), what I meant to type. If you refresh the answer, you'll see the updated code.

Comment: What I was needing to do was open the .dat file to read the 6 lines and then close the file when done reading it

Comment: @NicholasFoxworthy I've added an example using fopen, fgets, and fclose.

Comment: Do they no longer need brackets with numbers in them?

Comment: In the file function example, you're accessing an array elements which correspond with the file line numbers. In the "old school" example, you're accessing a file resource ($personalinfo) with the function fgets, which automatically advances to the next line in the file every time it's called. So, no, the second example doesn't need the brackets.