# PHP dat file reading

Tags: c#, php

I have C# code piece which I need to convert it into PHP to process further for encryption.
Here is the C# code:

```
using (var instream = new FileStream("./salt.dat", FileMode.Open)){
    saltBytes = new byte[32]; 
    instream.Read(saltBytes, 0, 32);
}
```

I tried with `fopen(dirname(__FILE__)."/salt.dat")` or `file(dirname(__FILE__)."/salt.dat")` or `file_get_contents(dirname(__FILE__).'/salt.dat')` but it didn't work. is there any way to get the dat file content so that I can pass the content as an array or string?

Comment: Open file, read 32 bytes. Be happy.

Comment: https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.fread.php

Comment: @Llama I have tried your suggestion before `$handle = fopen('salt.dat', "r"); $contents = fread($handle, 32); fclose($handle);` and I get the content �+���M֑4��e�T<��˝�T���34ө is this normal?

Comment: @tufanayd please refer this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28424647/how-to-retrieve-individual-lines-of-data-from-a-dat-file-using-php/28424764

Comment: That output looks potentially normal for a text representation of some binary data, yes

Comment: You're treating something that should be completely random binary data (it's a salt) as a string. You're naturally going to get strange looking data because it's never intended to be interpreted as a string. Perhaps try something like `echo bin2hex($contents);` and see if it matches `BitConvert.ToString(saltBytes).Replace("-", "")` from your C# code?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

```
$file = file_get_contents('./salt.dat');
```